# Dynamically using ng-selected for <select> tag with data loaded from server

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select, angularjs-select

I am trying to properly set a series of SELECT objects that are dynamically created in angular. The server returns an array of objects that I create these dropdowns from.

What I'd like to do is, for every dropdown created, assign the default selected value (as in, set ng-selected) based on the value of the object's value (labelled 'package')

The function changeValue changes the data on the server successfully.

Here is the code so far:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div ng-repeat="package in bucket.packages">
<select  ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in sources' ng-change="changeValue('source', package.id, selection)" ng-model="selection"></select>
</div>


//js
  $scope.sources = [
    {name: 'License Source'},
    {name: 'Project Website', value: 'projectWebsite'},
    {name: 'File', value: 'file'},
    {name: 'Expected License', value: 'expectedLicense'}
  ];


  $scope.optionMatches = function (selection, option){
    return selection === option.value;
  };


//not sure where to put this
ng-selected="optionMatches(package, option)"
```

Comment: what type of object is "$scope.source" and "$scope.selection" and what function is "$scope.changeValue()"?

Comment: I do not use $scope.source anywhere, but the string 'source' is used for saving the data on the back end. $scope.sources is the array in the javascript I've listed, used for making all of the options.

Selection is used on ng-model, and it binds the value of the SELECT object to a variable in the js.

I also described above that changeValue is used for saving the data on the server.

Comment: Can you elaborate this? What is the content of `bucket.packages`?